# Do not import `@jest/globals` outside of the Jest test environment

Tags: lwc-jest

I am using jest 25.5.1 , i am receiving error as "Do not import '@jest/globals' i see in this version it is not supported . Could you please help how to resolve this issue either how to downgrade or upgrade to the version which is working!

"_from": "babel-jest@^25.5.1",
"_id": "babel-jest@25.5.1",